# Flow can't assign property: assignment of computed property/element

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to add property in the object like this:

```
request(options:HttpRequestData): Promise<any> {
    options.headers = options.headers || {};

    options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';  // Error

    return this._request(options);
}
```

But it has error:

```
options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
assignment of computed property/element. Computed property/element cannot be assigned on possibly undefined value
```

HttpRequestData is a object type:

```
type HttpRequestData = {
    url:string,
    method:string,
    headers?:Object,
    body?:string,
};
```

Assiging just one value into options.header(in this case, 'Accept') works but it fails when I try two or more.

What the difference between single assigning and multiple assigning in Flow, and how to assign those properties into options.headers object?

Any advice will very appreciate it.

Comment: it seems, there's no type Object, in flow. I mean it's incorrect syntax for object type.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv Thanks, so I just updated headers property like this: headers?:{ [string]: string } but still same error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like this:

```
request(options:HttpRequestData): Promise<any> {
    options.headers = options.headers || {};

    const modifiedHeaders = options.headers;
    modifiedHeaders['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    modifiedHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

    options.headers = modifiedHeaders;

    return this._request(options);
}
```

Now no more error message.